# How to keep font size constant in Inkscape during rescaling?

Tags: inkscape

I came across a problem in Inkscape I couldn't solve on my own. Currently I am creating sketches etc. for a LaTex document in Inkscape. Drawing the sketches works fine and adding text to it as well. Then I would just save it as pdf (+ this tex option) and then import it in LaTex using

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \input{testfile.pdf_tex}
    \label{fig:testfile}
    \caption{This is just a testfile}
\end{figure}
```

The font size and type in the sketch after compiling the document remains always the same as in the rest of my LaTex document.

However, placing the text in the right position requires a lot of iterative steps, because rescaling the sketch in Inkscape (I might find the sketch too big or too small for example) would rescale the text as well - again, just in Inkscape, luckily not in LaTex.

How do I prevent the text in Inkscape to be rescaled? Everything that should change during rescaling is the absolute position of the text boxes while the relative position and font size should remain constant.

Comment: This might be relevant if I dont want to compile the sketch in LaTex first or if I want to use different font sizes in the same sketch

Comment: This isn't how Inkscape is meant to work, I think. However, you can make note of the font size before rescaling, then after scaling select a text, right-click on it, do Select Same > Object type and then with all texts selected, change the font size back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this Inkscape extension [Scientific-Inkscape](https://github.com/burghoff/Scientific-Inkscape) to be very useful.
I cite one of its features "Scale Plots: Changes the size or aspect ratio of a plot without modifying its text and ticks. Especially useful for assembling multi-panel figures."

See also a scaling example here:

[image]